# Is there a way to list files that can be recovered from rdiff-backup

Tags: ubuntu, backup, backup-restoration, rdiff-backup

I am testing `rdiff-backup` as a possible backup solution.  There is one thing i cant find how to do and was wonder if it is possible.

If I am backing up directories on a server.  e.g. *server:/shareddir*

If I delete a file in *server:/shareddri/some/directory* but don't know its name, is there any way to get a list of the files that `rdiff-backup` has in it's backup?   From what I can see, to restore you need to know about the file already.

Answer (score 3):

The following will list the contents of a sub-directory

`rdiff-backup -v6 --list-at-time "<time>" /shareddir/some/directory`

And will work for any subdirectory or the root backed up folder.